# NodeJS google cloud function request not defined

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, stripe-payments

I’m trying to write some NodeJS for a google cloud function to process stripe. I’m pretty new to this and trying to follow various tutorials.

I currently get the following error:

```
 Detailed stack trace: ReferenceError: request is not defined
```

I don’t really understand since request I thought is part of express package. This is my entire code. It’s designed to take a token from the form and create a charge. Even looking at the stripe tutorial they don’t separately define request.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var stripe = require('stripe')(
  "sk_);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//get token from body
const token = request.body.stripeToken;

//initiate a one-off charge for a customer
exports.chargeCustomer = app.get("/", function      chargeCustomer (req,res){
stripe.charges.create({
source: token,
currency: 'usd',
amount:999
 },function(err, charge) {
  if(err) {
  return res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
  }
  res.send(JSON.stringify(charge));
  });
  });
```

Comment: `request.body` is just an example. On Google Cloud you likely want to read https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http

Comment: there is no need for `app.get()` when writing these serverless functions. That becomes the job of this line of code `exports.createUser = functions.https.onRequest(createUser);`, which makes requiring in http module unnecessary as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what tutorial you followed, so can't point to that. What's missing from your code is the first request to the [tokens](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card?lang=node) endpoint that creates the card token, which is needed for the subsequent `charges` call.

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_XXXXXXX"); // your test key

stripe.tokens.create({
  card: {
    number: '4242424242424242',
    exp_month: 12,
    exp_year: 2020,
    cvc: '123'
  }
}, function(err, token) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

The result of this will return a JSON object, and you will need the `id` of that object. The ID is a string starts with `tok_`, i.e. `tok_0EDyAkDOjEFp8g5k9NxTrm2k`